# No permission to share Outlook calendar

Tags: powershell, office365

One of the users in our tenant seemingly can't update the sharing permissions for their calendar. Both Outlook and OWA has some uninformative error message. I moved on to powershell...

In Powershell I ran

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity a@domain.no:\Kalender -User b@domain.no -AccessRights Reviewer
```

, but got the error

```
Your request can't be completed. Du har ikke tillatelse til å dele denne kalenderen.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-MailboxFolderPermission], InvalidRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=AM7P191MB0932,RequestId=7ba70b47-f1f7-4cf2-9e2e-2a7dd115da24,TimeStamp=10.02.2021 09:55:50] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-InvalidRequestException] B4D39019,M 
   icrosoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.AddMailboxFolderPermission
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

I don't know why only part of the error is in Norwegian, but let me translate:

```
Your request can't be completed. You dont have permission to share this calendar.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I try to share a calendar via the `Add-MailboxFolderPermission` cmdlet, also with `Reviewer` access rights and I receive the same error message. However what I can do is to set `Editor` permissions to the same calender. Very strange behaviour.

Comment: Ohh, I just noticed I can share the calendar with Editor access rights, but I get the error if I try to grant Reviewer or AvailabilityOnly rights. Very strange indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I created a support ticket with MS.

They told me to run: outlook.exe /resetnavpane on the users computer.

After I ran it I was able to share the calendar as expected. I don't know why, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to grant `Reviewer` permissions. I followed [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/l9u8sx/o365_calendar_sharing_issue_you_dont_have/gm2jxdr?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) reddit thread. A user had indeed added his own calendar to the 'Shared Calendars' section in Outlook. So I removed his calendar and I was able to set the permissions to `Reviewer` accordingly.

Comment: I've removed everything from `Shared calendars` except the obligatory `People in the organization`. Guess I'm opening a ticket with MS.